# Add Unique Index on Union View (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, view, indexing

I have a view which combines two tables using `UNION ALL`.

Is it possible to create a unique index on the view?

Comment: Yes, but was throwing errors... looks like there's no workaround for this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot create an indexed view if the view is using UNION, this was true in SQL 2000 and is still true in 2008, see also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921(SQL.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Indexed views cannot contain the `UNION` operator: see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933148%28SQL.80%29.aspx)